# How to automatically insert a word I marked inside a <text area> that is inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

Automatically inserts a word I marked into  that is inside the iframe.

This is a chrome plugin

```html
<html>
    <iframe id="iframe" frameborder="0"  src="http://www.maozakor.co.il/demo/default.aspx">
    </iframe>
    
    <img id="photo" src="https://i.imgur.com/q91Y1ly.png" style="max-width: 100%; min-height: 175px;">

    <style>
    body {
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    #iframe {
        position: absolute;
        overflow:hidden;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: -70px;
    }
          
    #photo {position: relative;
        top: 80px;
        left: 800px;
        z-index: 21003005 ;
    }
    </style>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't modify the contents of an iframe from a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved providing you have access to edit the code both inside the iframe, and outside. You need to set up a message listener on the inside of the iframe that listens for the word you send in, and inserts it into the document.

Have a look at Window.postMessage() here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

I have not tried this with chrome-plugins, but I can confirm that it works cross-domain in regular websites.